# How to access a string from a string Array?

Tags: android, arrays, string

I'm brand new to android developing, so I'm sorry if this is a terrible rookie mistake.

That being said, I know in java, if I have a string array named example, I could just do
example[0] to access the first string. I'm basically making a quiz app where it will put answers in a random order, but I don't believe I can just accesss the string array in string resources (my values/strings.xml) with this method? Thanks.

Comment: `Resources res = getResources();
 String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.Question1Answers);` I have that, but the "array" in R.array.Question1Answers is red underlined.

Comment: can you show us how your Question1Answer is declared?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: some reason it's putting a red line under "array" in R.array

Comment: @user1705070 `array` should be changed to the name of your string array declared in strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Strings from Resources this way:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).